# Nodejs Winston Emit to socket

Tags: node.js, socket.io, winston

I have implemented Winston to log my nodejs app.
Currently I am writing the log to log files using the "DailyRotateFile" transport of Winston, and outputting the log data to the console.

I want to add an additional transport that emits the log message to a socket so that I can output it to the web interface I have created using Express, through socket.io.

This is the current way I have set up Winston:

```
  var logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
            level: 'info',
            filename: './Logs/server',
            datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-dd.log',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: true,
            maxsize: 5242880, // 5MB
            maxFiles: 5,
            colorize: false
        }),
        new winston.transports.Console({
            level: 'debug',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: false,
            colorize: true
        })
    ],
    exitOnError: false
})
```

This is the code the I currently use to emit the log message:

```
var logStream = logger.stream({
    start: -1
})

logStream.on('log', function(log){
    console.log('LOG STREAM')
    //console.log(log)
    io.emit('logger', log);
})
```

This however continuously outputs "LOG STREAM" to the nodejs console when I start the server, and doesn't emit anything when I use the logger.info command.

**EDIT**
So it looks like the reason the it continues to output "LOG STREAM" is because it is sending all the messages that have been saved in the log file, even though I set "start -1"

I would really appreciate any suggestions as how to correctly achieve this. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to achieve sending Winston logs to the browser

I added the following transport:

```
new winston.transports.Webhook({
            host: '192.168.51.242',
            port: 8102,
        }),
```

I then created a TCP port to receive the log messages:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var logMsg = '';
    req.on('data', function(data){
        logMsg += data.toString()
    })
    req.on('end', function(data){
        io.emit('logger', logMsg)
    })
}).listen(8102)
```

every time I receive data to the port, I emit it using Socket.IO to my Angualr interface

Comment: i got follow error and i cannot found any docs about winston webhook

> TypeError: winston.transports.Webhook is not a function

Comment: Winston 2.0 removed Webhook transports. Use Http instead

Answer (score 1):

I have written a custom SocketioTransport transport class with an overridden log that emits the log via socket.io function.

```
import Transport = require('winston-transport');

class SocketioTransport extends Transport {
    constructor(options?: Transport.TransportStreamOptions) {
        super(options);
    }

    log(info: any, callback: any) {
        setImmediate(() => {
            this.emit('logged', info);
        });

        // Send the log message via Socket.IO
        io.emit('log', {
            level: info.level,
            message: info.message,
            timestamp: info.timestamp,
            // Add any other metadata you want to send
            // metadata: info.metadata,
        });

        callback();
    }
}

export const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    transports: [
        new SocketioTransport(),
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'logs.log' }),
    ],
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize(),
        winston.format.timestamp(),
        winston.format.printf(({ timestamp, level, message }) => {
            return `[${timestamp}] ${level}: ${message}`;
        })
    ),
});
```