# How to use winston to send logs to my frontend using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, winston

Cannot figure out how to get the winston logs and send that data to my frontend using socket.io

I looks like someone was able to send logs using winston.transport.WebHook but Winston 2.0 removed the Webhook method: [Nodejs Winston Emit to socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628795/nodejs-winston-emit-to-socket)

Someone recommended to http transport but cant figure out how to use it